# How do I extract the value of a solution returned by Solve?

Tags: equation-solving

For instance, I have an equation to be solved:

```
Solve[c == 0, c]
```

And of course, the result is `{{c -> 0}}`.

What I need is the result `0`. I know that `First` can eliminate the brackets, but then the result becomes `c -> 0`. It is not what I want. So what shall I do?

Comment: `c /. Solve[..]`, `c /. First@Solve[..]` or `Values @ Solve[..]`....

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/4999 (possible duplicate)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Problem solved, thanks!

Comment: `c /. Solve[c == 0, c][[1]]` or `c /. Flatten[Solve[c == 0, c]]`